# Duplicate text in svg with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, svg

I have the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/jdAYlcfO5GDru0MMa2fM?p=preview

```
$.fn.canvas = function(options){
    var hids = $(this).find(':hidden');
    source = $(this).get(0);
    html2canvas(source, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      }
    });
  };
```

After click on save, text inside svg get printed twice.

Thats not what desired.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use
    `document.body.replaceChild(document.body,canvas);`

Comment: i get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

Comment: can you give plunkr link

Comment: sorry my mistake. I edit my post, it should work now.

Comment: no it doesnt  DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent